# Docker Tomcat exited 0 after run

Tags: tomcat, docker

I made an image from a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM tomcat:8.0
COPY target/javahello.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

But right after start - it's in "exited":

```
$ sudo docker run -ti 957a86defe4f
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

And:

```
$ sudo docker ps -a | head
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                     COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS                     NAMES
dc2309620baf        957a86defe4f:latest                                                       "/bin/sh -c /usr/loc   25 seconds ago      Exited (0) 24 seconds ago                               insane_elion
```

`logs` show nothing:

```
$ sudo docker logs dc2309620baf
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

If I run `startup.sh` directly from container - Tomcat works as expected:

```
$ sudo docker run -ti 957a86defe4f bash
root@b00b541e6ccb:/usr/local/tomcat# ./bin/startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
# ps -axu | grep tomcat
root        15 44.7  1.1 6258648 193484 ?      Sl   14:54   0:04 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Is it something wrong with my `CMD`?

Answer (score 4):

The tomcat with `startup.sh` will start tomcat in the background (as a service) and docker will exit with `code 0` which is normal and expected behavior.

In this case you need to start tomcat as foreground process with `catalina.sh run`.

```
 FROM tomcat:8.0
 COPY target/javahello.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
 EXPOSE 8080
 CMD /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
```

When you run `startup.sh` inside container  it is working because  you are in "`bash`" (your foreground process).