# Google Cloud Run error: Container failed to start (DSS - Digital Signature Service)

Tags: docker, cloud, gcloud

i'm trying to get the following docker container running on the google cloud. The container works locally. In the cloud shell, the container also works with "docker run". On the google cloud i can see the port 8080 web preview. When I create a service, the container does not start. The log only says "tomcat started, container called exit (0)".

I added address = 0.0.0.0 to the connector in the server.xml. But that didn't work either.

Maybe someone can give me a hint.
Thank you
Tom

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine

RUN  apk update && apk add unzip

ADD https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/artifact/repository/esignaturedss/eu/europa/ec/joinup/sd-dss/dss-demo-bundle/5.8.1/dss-demo-bundle-5.8.1.zip /tmp
RUN unzip /tmp/dss-demo-bundle-5.8.1.zip -d /tmp
RUN mv /tmp/dss-demo-bundle-5.8.1 /dss

RUN chmod +x /dss/apache-tomcat-8.5.61/bin/catalina.sh

COPY ./startup.sh /dss/

ENTRYPOINT [ "/dss/startup.sh" ]
CMD [ "/bin/sh" ]
```

This is the sourcecode of startup.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
echo "`/bin/sh /dss/apache-tomcat-8.5.61/bin/startup.sh`"
exec "$@"
```

Comment: According to this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157992/docker-tomcat-exited-0-after-run), I believe you should start tomcat as foreground process with ```catalina.sh run```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, the solution was, i change the tomcat startup to "catalina.sh run", to start tomcat as forground process.

The second thing: i had to remove the "address = 0.0.0.0" in the tomcat server.xml file

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
echo "`/bin/sh /dss/apache-tomcat-8.5.61/bin/catalina.sh run`"
exec "$@"
```